# Is this 52 inch fan too big for this bedroom?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a 52 in fan that is in a bedroom. The room is 10ft by 11ft. Could this fan cause some issues if it is turned on? Maybe too fast?

[image: picture of fan]

Comment: What sort of issues are you concerned about?  Unless it's hitting the walls the size is subjective based on your preference for appearance and performance.

Comment: As long as it is mounted well, there should not be problems except for too much air movement(on high blowing papers all over).

Comment: The lowest fan speed setting might move too much air for some people, but if it's acceptable to you that's what matters. Is the speed continuously variable or does it have several discrete speeds?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Answer (score 4):

It will not cause issues. In fact, larger fans tend to be quieter since they don't have to turn as fast to move the same volume of air. Just use the appropriate speed. If the lowest speed is too fast, you may be able to use a fan speed switch at the wall to create slower speeds. This would depend on your wiring.